# Getting sms while phone is asleep

Tags: android

I have an app that receives sms (via BroadCastReceiver) and starts an Activity to handle incoming sms (including playing a sound to notify user, updating database and showing a message to user).

The problem is that sometimes that app is not running and mobile is asleep, I receive nothing but as soon as I unlock screen, I got 4 or 5 messages together!

EDIT:
Definition of BroadcastReceiver:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".util.sms.SmsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:port="56790" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Definition of my Activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    </activity>
```

Inside Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // ...
            handleNewMessage(this.getIntent());
    }


@Override
public void onNewIntent (Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    handleNewMessage(intent);       
}
```

Starting MyActivity from BroadcastReceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //...
        if( smsIsMine() ) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE_BODY", sms.getBody());
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setClass(context, MyActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);                
        }
    }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use WakeLock as below"

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();
    // your code ...
    wl.release();
}
```

Comment: Does this need permission ?

Answer (score 1):

Register your Receiver in Manifest. Like this:

```
<receiver android:name="com.app.SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true"> 
        <intent-filter android:priority="999"> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I did this and I am testing. Would you please give me more details on how this will solve the problem?

Comment: I need to see your code for that. I am assuming that you are registering your receiver from inside an activity. When you do this broadcast receiver un-registers itself as soon as the activity closes or goes to onPause state. When you register in manifest, irrespective of app status (open, close, in background) the broadcast receiver receives the intent and executes the onReceive() of BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: I register receiver in manifest (just like you) and everything is ok almost the time. But sometimes something I explained happens and I think that something is wrong with android itself like sleeping after a period of time in idle mode.

Comment: in your onReceive() method you are not setting any action in intent. is that expected?

Comment: I just start an activity. The problem s there! Sometimes I received 3 4 text messages but activity does not start as expected and when I unlock phone (or have a call) all of them fires together!